# Create a blank admin page from plugin

Tags: plugins, pages, admin

is there an opportunity to create a blank admin page in wordpress from a plugin or theme? I mean like the theme customizer without the admin bar or the sidebar menu.

Jonathan

Comment: If there is no menu then it is not really an admin page, no? but technically yes, you can use CSS to hide anything.

Comment: But I need the admin scripts to be included and want to avoid loading the rest of the page because of the loading time. I want to load an iframe of the actual side to edit it in "live mode" like the theme customizer.

Comment: I've tried nothing so far because I didn't find a way to do

Answer (score 0):

its completely possible to create a empty page in WordPress. I know my answer is pretty late but maybe this helps others with the same problem.

The trick is to register a custom endpoint like:
`example.com/myendpoint`

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'myendpoint';

    return $vars;

} );


add_action( 'init', function() {

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'myendpoint', EP_ROOT );

} );
```

And then load a custom template for this endpoint:

```
add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

    if( get_query_var( 'myendpoint', false ) !== false ):

        return HERE_YOUR_TEMPLATE_URL;

    else:

        return $template;

    endif;

} );
```

When adding this code you have to save your permalink settings once.